# How can i read a .ppm into an array of 3 columns using Awk

Tags: arrays, awk

I am still new to awk, I am trying to read a ppm file using awk into columns of three:
Example:

```
P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
 0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0   15  0 15
 0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0    0  0  0
 0  0  0    0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0
15  0 15    0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0
```

i want to get columns containing

```
P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
15 0 15
```

```
P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
0 0 0
0 15 7
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

and so on until the end of number fields. my code looks like below:

```
BEGIN{
    #fieldsep=" ";
}
NR>0{
    count = 0;
    while(count < NF){
        print $((count +1)), $((count+2)), $((count+3));
        count +=3;
    }

}

END{

}
```

Comment: After reading the [format specifications](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html), your output is an invalid ppm, you should have 1 4

Comment: How do i do it for a valid ppm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk isn't shell. It's a completely different tool with it's own syntax and semantics that are far more similar to `C` than to shell. To add `1` to a variable named `count` in awk is simply `count+1`, just like in `C`, surrounding that with `$((...))` has a completely different meaning than it does in shell. If `count` has the value `3` then `count+1` is `4` and `$((count+1))` = `$((3+1))` = `$((4))` = `$4` = whatever value your 4th input field has.

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR<5 { hdr = (NR>1 ? hdr ORS : "") $0; next }
{
    ++numRows
    numCols = 3
    numBlocks = NF / numCols
    fldNr = 1
    for (blockNr=1; blockNr<=numBlocks; blockNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            vals[blockNr,numRows] = (colNr>1 ? vals[blockNr,numRows] OFS : "") $(fldNr++)
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (blockNr=1; blockNr<=numBlocks; blockNr++) {
        print hdr
        for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
            print vals[blockNr,rowNr]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
15 0 15

P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
0 0 0
0 15 7
0 0 0
0 0 0

P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 15 7
0 0 0

P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
15 0 15
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: I am getting nothing tried following your implementation but its printing nothing

Comment: As you can see in my answer when the script I wrote is run against the input you provided it produces the output you asked for so either a) you didn't copy/paste my script correctly or b) your real input doesn't look like the input you posted.

Comment: My bad it works the ppm was the problem thanks a lot